# An expression for someone who teaches in people's home

Tags: word-request, idioms, vocabulary

Is there a short expression for a teacher that teaches to his/her pupils in their homes, as opposed to in a classroom ?

My guess would be *home teacher* but I'm not sure (it is unclear if *home* refers to the teacher's home or his pupils)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the UK, the most common term would be "*private tutor*". They might also be called a "*home tutor*" or possibly "*personal tutor*", but the teaching could be in any setting, not just a personal home. Being taught individually by a professional but not in a school setting is nearly always referred to as "*private tuition*".

'Tutor' tends to be preferred over 'teacher' when the training is personal, tailored to the individual.

Comment: By default, AmE results dominate NGram queries, but when I look for all 6 permutations of ***a home tutor,a personal tutor,a private tutor,a home teacher,a personal teacher,a private teacher*** (link too long for a comment), ***a private tutor*** is way out in front, with everything else except ***a private teacher*** effectively "flatlining" by comparison.

Comment: And as a note about varying usage, in the US "tuition" is limited to fees and has nothing to do with actual instruction.